# OpenVPN and Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, openvpn

I have a custom made C (cross-platform) application. An OpenVPN variant. I want to compille this for the Android version with NDK.

It compiles under Linux. Does this mean i can easily compile it for Andoird too with the NDK? And if so, how can i communicate with my library through Java code (the normal Android SDK)?

I'm not really that far yet to do the actual implementation part. But i'd like to know what i can expect in advance.

So if you have any experience with the NDK and have any tips/pointers for me, then you'd really help me alot. Like, things i should look out for when working with the NDK. Compile settings etc.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Openvpn for Android application is open sourced. See https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/ Since you wrote that you are using an OpenVPN variant looking at the Android.mk files of my project might help you.